# How to execute asynchronous code in a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I tried to keep this in a loop but webpage freezes every time I try to keep this in the loop. Any suggestion how to get location live update by this?

```
function hello(){
   for(var i=0;i<=10;i++){  
      if(i==10){
         call();
         i=0;
     }
}

function call(){
  var settings = {
    "url": "https://pos.ls.hereapi.com/positioning/v1/locate?apiKey=imnotgoingtoshareliveapikeyeveragain",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({"lte":[{"mcc":404,"mnc":49,"cid":231706401}]}),
  };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: can you post your loop? code

Comment: Whenever do you need to execute call() function?

Comment: location frequency say every 10sec! @AhedKabalan

Comment: I suggest regenerating the API key and not posting a live API keys inside questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (every 10 seconds will trigger call function):

```js
function call(){
    var settings = {
      "url": "https://pos.ls.hereapi.com/positioning/v1/locate?apiKey=s_WF6U2g60ucHbmnYIyuieeUWnkT0jshGf4mD33kpwI",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "data": JSON.stringify({"lte":[{"mcc":404,"mnc":49,"cid":231706401}]}),
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  function hello(){
     setInterval(function(){ call() }, 10000);
  };

  hello();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing two separate functions, you can use `setInterval` to run every x seconds:

```
var settings = {
    "url": "https://pos.ls.hereapi.com/positioning/v1/locate?apiKey=s_WF6U2g60ucHbmnYIyuieeUWnkT0jshGf4mD33kpwI",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({"lte":[{"mcc":404,"mnc":49,"cid":231706401}]}),
  };

setInterval(function(){ 


 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });



 }, 10000);
```